# A-Frame: parent's raycaster-intersected-cleared triggered if no intersection with children

Tags: aframe

I'm implementing a feature to get coordinate of an `a-sky` while moving the VR controller.

```html
<a-scene scenelistener>
  <a-sky
    id="map-sky"
    color="#222"
    radius="700"
    rotation="0 45 0"
    rotation-control
    raycaster-listen
    class="ray-castable"
  >
    <a-entity
      id="country-tiles"
      country-tiles
      scale="1 1 1"
      rotation="0 90 0"
    ></a-entity>
  </a-sky>
  ... // Oculus entities
</a-scene>
```

`a-sky` and its children is listening for raycasting, and print out the console logging

```html
AFRAME.registerComponent("raycaster-listen", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected", evt => {
      console.log(`raycaster ${this.el.id} intersected!!!`);
    });
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected-cleared", evt => {
      console.log(`raycaster ${this.el.id} cleared!!!`);
    });
  }
});
```

RESULT: while moving in and out the children `country-tiles`, `raycaster-intersected-cleared` event is triggered from the children and also its parent `map-sky`, mean A-Frame cannot get the intersections between `a-sky` and the raycasting VR controller.

```
raycaster  intersected!!!
raycaster map-sky intersected!!!
// Moving out the tile
raycaster  cleared!!!
raycaster map-sky cleared!!!
```

You can check on this [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/skitter-celestial-danger)

NOTE: since I am developing for VR controller, therefore please use the [WebXR emulator](https://blog.mozvr.com/webxr-emulator-extension/) extension for interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `raycaster-intersected-cleared` event from parent element is fired but it does not mean that it is not intersected anymore. To confirm if it has been still intersected I have to check if `getIntersection` result is NULL.

```html
AFRAME.registerComponent("raycaster-listen", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected", evt => {
      console.log(`raycaster ${this.el.id} intersected!!!`);
      this.raycaster = evt.detail.el;
    });
    this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected-cleared", evt => {
      if (this.raycaster) {
        const intersection = this.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(this.el);
        if (!intersection) {
          console.log(`raycaster ${this.el.id} cleared!!!`);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```